# Full page screenshot API (iOS13)

Tags: ios

Sorry for the dumb question - but does anyone know where the API documentation is for the new full page screenshot feature in iOS13.

I want to add support within my app.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3213938-screenshotservice ?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is `UIScreenshotService` and its associated delegate.

Comment: Asking where the docs are is off topic. Answering an off topic question is off topic too.

Comment: Do a search for UIScreenshotService on StackOverflow - not a single hit - which leads me to believe this is something that is not well known - which is what stack overflow is all about. Now when someone searches for 'full page screenshot' they will find this and know where to start.

Comment: i think this is useful, specially when you search "full page screenshot" iOS 13 and there is a lot of blog post regarding how to use the feature for safari, but not about how to implement it

Comment: FTR, I was trying to find the docs for this feature, and couldn't. I wound up here on StackOverflow, and immediately found what I was looking for 